# Python - Calling Functions from File I/O

Tags: python, io

I've been given a text file with a list of names in the format

ID Year CourseCode OtherNames LastName
for example
1234567 5 X500 Xrin Stack

Now I've written a code to open the file and i have two functions
One function needs to store the data into a tuple (in a list)
The second function needs to format the tuple i.e fixed widths.

However I'm slightly confused as to why my code doesn't work. I think its to do with calling the function within the main body of the text

```
def student(l,reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name):
    if not isinstance(reg, int) or \
       not isinstance(year, int) or \
       not isinstance(degree, str) or \
       not isinstance(other_name, str) or \
       not isinstance(last_name, str) :
       print("Invalid string argument")
    elif 0<=year<=4:
        l.append((reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name))
    else: print("Invalid year")

    return l


def printStud(student):
    reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student
    reg=int(reg)
    year=int(year)
    fullName=last_name+ ", " + other_name
    #thisYear="Year" + str(year)
    print(format(fullName, "<32s")+format(reg,"<7d")+format(degree,">6s")+format(year,">6s"))

try:
    filename = input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
    f = open(filename,"r")
    readFile = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in readFile:
        print(printStud(student))
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Failed to open",filename)
```

So what i want to do is
Open the file, store each item in the list as a tuple (multiple lines hence why using a for loop for the read lines)
And then format the tuple for fixed width but i have a problem that lies somewhere.
Currently my code error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\exercise1.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(printStud(student))
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\exercise1.py", line 22, in printStud
    reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: As you can there's error at reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student. Here LHS != RHS

Answer (score 1):

```
def printStud(student):
    reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student.strip().split(" ")
    reg=int(reg)
    year=int(year)
    fullName=last_name+ ", " + other_name
    #thisYear="Year" + str(year)
    print(format(fullName, "<32s")+format(reg,"<7d")+format(degree,">6s")+format(year,">6s"))
```

This should fix the problem, given file has same structure i.e. all information are separated by space and each line has 5 words.

e.g.

```
1234 1990 B.Tech Foo Bar
1235 1991 B.Tech Bob Alice
```

If you have some other separator then update then update `reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student.strip().split(" ")` with correct seperator or may be use try catch.

Comment: Well each piece of information is spaced but some people may have 2 "Other names" for example FirstName MiddleName LastName

Comment: There could be single name as well e.g. Joe, you have to handle this as well.

Comment: That's correct, it may have one name or two names,so how would i handle this? Making a seperate variable that combines the two names or?

Comment: You can use list/tuples and check their length and do something based on this. It's homework so only hint is provided here.

Comment: Okay, but for when it initially prints, after the first line, underneath is says "None"  before printing the next line on another line. Why does it print None

Comment: Since in Python every function's **default** return  value is None. You have to remove print or alter the function to return the correct value.

Comment: I made it work almost, however for example Joe S Smith it assumes S Smith as last_name and Joe as other_name. How do i make the S part of the other_name? reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student.strip().split(" ",4)

Answer (score 0):

The preffered way to iterate over the contents of a file with Python is using a `with` block and iterating over the file itself, like so:

```
try:
    filename = input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(printStud(line))
```

I think the error itself stems from the fact that you were calling `printStud(student)`, where student is the name of a function you defined earlier. I changed that to the contents of the line in the file, which is probably what you actually want. Try this and tell me if it works.